# How to alter the background color of a <select> tag dynamically using Angular 2+?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have been having trouble formatting the background of a **select** tag using ngStyle.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control colores" [ngStyle] = "selectedStyle">
    <option [value]="i" *ngFor="let i of colors" (click)="changeColor(i)" [ngStyle] = "{backgroundColor: setColor(i)}"></option>
</select>
```

And the typescript code is this:

```
selectedStyle = 'orange';

setColor(color) {
   return color;
}

changeColor(color){
   this.selectedStyle = color;
}
```

The **options** do have their background colors assigned correctly. However, it seems changeColor(i) is not being executed because I have {{selectedStyle}} and it doesn't change when I select a different one. Does anybody see the problem?

Comment: Since `selectedStyle` is in fact only a color, you can do this: `[style.background-color]="selectedStyle"`.

Comment: If I use it, it only changes the background of the select. I think the problem is in the changeColor()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color':selectedStyle}"
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Try to look at it from a beginner's perspective. Someone who can understand it without explanation could have written it themselves.

Comment: okay, thanks... you're right... basically, other that using [ngStyle], and setting the property **value** (the background color stored in "selectedStyle" variable), we need to specify the property itself we will want to affect \ bind to. in this case the "background-color" is the one, and it is recieved as an object with curly braces as I wrote above. this is another way to do so (as mensioned above) => [style.background-color]="selectedStyle".

Comment: Awesome, thanks! And, if you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48935444/edit) that information into your answer, with code formatting, it will be much easier to read.